# How remove focused background when click in triangle in Kendo UI TreeView

Tags: kendo-treeview

How remove focused background when click in triangle in Kendo UI TreeView?

I like that focus only when I clic over the text (field "Item 2") and not the triangle icon. (see the picture)

thanks!

[image: TreeView demo]

Answer (score 0):

In my View the I use the TreeView, I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
    $(document).on("click", ".k-minus", function () {
        $("#myContainer.k-state-focused").removeClass("k-state-focused");
    });
</script>
```